# Linker errors with wxTreeListCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Developing an app with wxWidgets even though im fairly new too the library, and need some help fixing these linker problem;

i tried google first with no luck.

```
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "char const * const wxTreeListCtrlNameStr" (?wxTreeListCtrlNameStr@@3QBDB)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxEventHashTable & __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::GetEventHashTable(void)const " (?GetEventHashTable@wxTreeListCtrl@@MBEAAVwxEventHashTable@@XZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct wxEventTable const * __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::GetEventTable(void)const " (?GetEventTable@wxTreeListCtrl@@MBEPBUwxEventTable@@XZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: int __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::DoInsertColumn(class wxString const &,int,int,enum wxAlignment,int)" (?DoInsertColumn@wxTreeListCtrl@@AAEHABVwxString@@HHW4wxAlignment@@H@Z)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: virtual class wxWindowList __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::GetCompositeWindowParts(void)const " (?GetCompositeWindowParts@wxTreeListCtrl@@EBE?AVwxWindowList@@XZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::Init(void)" (?Init@wxTreeListCtrl@@AAEXXZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::~wxTreeListCtrl(void)" (??1wxTreeListCtrl@@UAE@XZ)
1>mainwindow.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall wxTreeListCtrl::Create(class wxWindow *,int,class wxPoint const &,class wxSize const &,long,class wxString const &)" (?Create@wxTreeListCtrl@@QAE_NPAVwxWindow@@HABVwxPoint@@ABVwxSize@@JABVwxString@@@Z)
```

i tried to format this into a code, but its so hard to do on this site

Comment: Formatting not so hard if you read the FAQ etc... So: have you got a basic wx "hello world" working?

Comment: can you post your bakefile. And the name of your sample ?

Comment: sorry but i read the FAQ page front, backwards, and sideways. And everything works fine except when i try and use wxTreeListCtrl.

Comment: I forgot too link a certain library but not sure which on it was.

I opened to treelist sample in the wxwidgets directory and copied its additional dependencies. Be sure if your project is in release you the 'd' character from those library names.  Wouldn't let me post this as an answer sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the advanced library in the list of wx libraries linked to.

This is mentioned in the wxTreeListCtrl documentation at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_list_ctrl.html

The documentation of every wxwidgets class mentions which library needs to be linked with when you use the class.

[image]

Comment: thanks but i fixed it already, just didn't brother see what library i linked that fixed it. I also tried looking for that info on the wxWidgets Documentation page but i guess i didn't scroll down far enough. lol i was thinking its was msdn and all the library and header info was at the bottom of the page.